# Get display name from hook_preprocess_views_view

Tags: 7, views, hooks

I want to use hook_preprocess_views_view in order for several views to share the same template, by adding theme_hook_suggestions as described in this article: http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2014/04/sharing-templates-between-multiple-drupal-views/

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {

  if (in_array(
    $vars['view']->name, array(
      'whatever'))) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] =
      'whatever';
  }
}
```

Problem is, I need to specify which display of the particular view it should apply to, rather than the whole view itself. I've tried printing the $vars out which results in a huge recurring array which doesn't seem to include the display name anywhere.

I'm also aware you do this via tagging in the views UI. The same problem occurs though - I can't add a tag to a particular display of a view.

If there is another way I can accomplish this I'm all ears!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the display ID through the `current_display` property of the View object, e.g.

```
$view = $vars['view'];
if ($view->name == 'foo' && $view->current_display == 'bar') {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh shhh... how did I not see that? Thanks!

Comment: Heh heh, I must have used this over a hundred times and I still go looking for `display_name` or `display_id` every time...

Comment: Now I have the problem that it's not picking up my template, but that's another question...

Comment: in drupal 8 you would use  `$view->id()` instead op the property name